RemoteConfig addOnConfigUpdateListener is not triggered
I try to implement a remote config in my Swift project. When I change the value of the remote config inside the Firebase console, it triggers the log inside Xcode. But sometimes, it triggers the addonconfiglistener function, when it's the first install, but addonconfiglistener is not triggered again after that.
I've tried to change the version from 10.23 to 10.25 without any apparent effect. How to resolve this issue?
10.23.0 - [FirebaseRemoteConfig][I-RCN000015] Received config update message on stream.
10.23.0 - [FirebaseRemoteConfig][I-RCN000039] Starting requesting token.
10.23.0 - [FirebaseInstallations][I-FIS002001] -[FIRInstallationsIDController installationWithValidAuthTokenForcingRefresh:0], appName: __FIRAPP_DEFAULT
10.23.0 - [FirebaseInstallations][I-FIS002000] -[FIRInstallationsIDController createGetInstallationItemPromise], appName: __FIRAPP_DEFAULT
10.23.0 - [FirebaseInstallations][I-FIS002000] -[FIRInstallationsIDController createGetInstallationItemPromise], appName: __FIRAPP_DEFAULT
10.23.0 - [FirebaseInstallations][I-FIS002001] -[FIRInstallationsIDController installationWithValidAuthTokenForcingRefresh:0], appName: __FIRAPP_DEFAULT

I access the remote config, when the app finishes launching:
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().setDefaults(fromPlist: "RemoteConfigDefaults")
        RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().fetch { status, error in
            print("this status \(status)")
          if status == .success {
              RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().activate { changed, error in
                  print("this changed \(changed)")
            }
          } else {
            print("Config not fetched")
            print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No error available.")")
          }
        }
        
        RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().addOnConfigUpdateListener { configUpdate, error in
          guard let configUpdate, error == nil else {
              print("Error listening for config updates: \(String(describing: error))")
              return
          }
            print("listener fetch")

            RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().activate { changed, error in
          }
        }
   }

